# Sub-pages always open domain root

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I'm having a strange problem with a new PHP page I´m writing. Everything seems to be loading/redirected to the domain root page.

- **domain.com** loads fine
- **domain.com/page** or **domain.com/page/index.php** always loads "domain.com" while retaining the /page/index.php in the browser URL.
- Even **domain.com/some_random_text** loads "domain.com"

I suspected the .htaccess file, but there is none to be found. There are no redirects in the PHP code.

If I remove the **domain.com/index.php** file I get an Internal Server Error when opening **domain.com/page/index.php**

This domain did have Wordpress installed, but I did uninstall that via cPanel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing to notice is that the `.htaccess` file can be anywhere in the path that is handled by Apache. So check everywhere. This kind of redirect could be made only like that.

This can only be done by Apache, so you might also like to check the apache config if you are running on a virtual machine or dedicated server.

Also, not that it might have been a wildcard redirect, added by the cPanel, so check those settings. Though I think those actually just modify the root `.htaccess` file.

Based on the data you provided I cannot say more, but I don't think this is a common issue.

Comment: I added more details to my answer. If you can give us more details so we could help you.

Comment: Thanks @itay-grudev. I spotted an .htaccess file from another sub-domain on the same server (multi domain cPanel account). After removing that file everything seems fine. Still strange that this was no affecting the site before.

Comment: @SkuliAxelson It probably was added/modified after the installation. I guess that it was supposed to revert it to normal, but something screwed up.